# Why is Typescript VSC extension not working?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I try to create a VSC extension with Typescript following the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension). If I create a new Extension Development Host window for testing the created extension and try to run the preconfigured `Hello World` from the command palette I get the following error:

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.test' failed: Cannot find module '/Users/maxhager/Projects2022/TextAutocompletionMarkdown/test/out/extension.js' Require stack: - /Applications/AppicationsMe/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js - /Applications/AppicationsMe/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js - /Applications/AppicationsMe/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork.js.
```

**Expected**

[image]

**Actual**

[image]

If I create an extension with Javascript and not Typescript everything works fine and I can run the command without an error.

**extensions.ts**

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "test" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('test.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from test!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "displayName": "test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.71.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:test.helloWorld"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "test.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.71.0",
    "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Define a "publisher" in your `package.json`.  Like `"publisher": "someNameHere",`.

Comment: Your extension.ts file is not transpiled yet, it seems. You have a watch task. Have you started that before running the extension host? You can do that automatically in your launch config.